# Characteristic and homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I got asked the following question: Let $R$ be a ring with characteristic $2$. Is $R \cong \mathbb{Z}/(2)$? The way I thought of it is the following. Let $\Phi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R , z \rightarrow 1 + \ldots + 1$ ($z$ times), if $z > 0, z \rightarrow 0$, if $z = 0$ and $z \rightarrow - (1+ \ldots + 1)$ ($z$ times). Then $\textrm{ker}(\phi) = (\textrm{char}(R))_\mathbb{Z}$. My question is, is $\phi$ surjective? In other words, does one get every element of $R$ just by adding $1$ over and over? This might be a fairly trivial question, however, I never really thought about it. This would then imply, that $R \cong \mathbb{Z}/(2)_\mathbb{Z}$ wouldn't it? Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: No, the finite field $\Bbb F_4$ is also a ring with characteristic $2$. What can you say about $\phi$ then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $\phi$ does not need to be surjective. A simple example is $R = (\mathbb{Z}/2)^n$. You could also consider a matrix ring over $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^n$ and any subring of $\operatorname{Mat}_m((\mathbb{Z}/2)^n)$ will also work.

Also a finite field of order $2^n$ will be characteristic $2$ and, by extension, any $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$-algebra will be characteristic $2$. For example
$$ \mathbb{F}_{16}[x,y,z]/(x - z^2, y - z^3). $$

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't think of that. The representation of $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^2$ for example is unique too, right? So if i have found one addition table of that ring, I automatically found every addition table, right?

Comment: @eu271828 I'm not 100% sure what you're asking but maybe this answers your question: If $R$ is characteristic $2$ then there is a map $f : \mathbb{Z}/2 \to R$. This map makes the additive group of $R$ into a $\mathbb{Z}/2$-vector space by $a \cdot v = f(a)v$ (where $a \in \mathbb{Z}/2$ and $v \in R$). Thus the additive group of $R$ is always isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^n$ by simply picking a basis for the vector space of $(R,0,+)$ over $\mathbb{Z}/2$. At least, this works if $R$ is finite. Otherwise your vector space has an infinite basis, you might need the axiom of choice, it's a mess.